# 2D rotation is leaving holes

Tags: java, bitmap, rotation, rendering, equation

i'm trying to create a 2d rotation without any luck, here's the code!

```
    public void render(int xPos, int yPos, double a, BitMap data){
    double angle = Math.toRadians(a);
    int xScr = 0;
    int yScr = 0;
    int CenterX = data.getWidth() / 2;
    int CenterY = data.getHeight() / 2;
    for(int y = 0; y < data.getHeight(); y++){
        yScr = (y + yPos);
        if(yScr < 0){
            continue;
        }
        else if(yScr >= height){
            return;
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < data.getWidth(); x++){
            xScr = (x + xPos);
            if(xScr < 0){
                continue;
            }
            if(yScr >= width){
                return;
            }
           int dataX = (int)(CenterX + (x - CenterX) * Math.cos(angle) - (y - CenterY) *Math.sin(angle));

           int dataY = (int)(CenterY + (x - CenterX) * Math.sin(angle) + (y - CenterY) * Math.cos(angle));

           if(dataX > 0 && dataX < data.getWidth()){
               if(dataY > 0 && dataY < data.getHeight()){
                    screenPixels.setValue(dataX, dataY, data.getValue(x, y));
               }
           }

        }
    }
}
```

The cube is rendering and is rotating, but it's leaving holes. I know it's because dataX and dataY is rounding of and there for there will be pixels left. I don't really know where to get started, and I would be really happy if someone could code write the code that's is missing, because i'm going to participate in Ludumdare this weekend and haven't still figured out this. Please, help me!

Comment: The "fix"is to work your way backwards from destination pixels to source pixels. This will ensure complete coverage.

Comment: Could you give me an example? Because I have heard that before but I don't really understand were to start with that statement.

Comment: You're looping through the source image and rotating the pixels into the destination image. This will cause "holes". Instead, loop through the destination image and find the source pixel positions by rotating in the opposite direction.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow, but if you have the time, write the code so I can give you a right answer thingie. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: So I managed to successfully do it, but now the rotation is weird. http://pastebin.com/hUWAq894

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code successfully rotates a bitmap, thanks to reddit.com/user/dd_123!

```
public void render2(int xPos, int yPos, double angle, BitMap data){
   double angle2 = Math.toRadians(angle);
   angle = angle2;
   int w = data.getWidth();
   int h  = data.getHeight();
   int size =  (int) (Math.sqrt(w * w + h * h));
   BitMap newBitMap = new BitMap(size, size);
   int xCenter = w / 2;
   int yCenter = h / 2;
   final int halfSize = size / 2;
   for(int y = 0; y < size; y++){
       for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){
          int samplePointX = x - halfSize;
          int samplePointY = y - halfSize;

          int xData, yData;
          xData = (int)(samplePointX * -Math.cos(angle) + samplePointY * Math.sin(angle));
          yData = (int)(samplePointX * -Math.sin(angle) - samplePointY * Math.cos(angle));
          xData += xCenter;
          yData += yCenter;
          if(!(xData >= 0 && xData < w)){
             continue;
          }
          if(!(yData >= 0 && yData < h)){
             continue;
          }
          if((x) + (y) * size > size * size){
             continue;
          }
          screenPixels.setValue(x, y, data.getValue(xData, yData));
       }
   }
```

}

The bitmap class

```
public class BitMap {

public BitMap(int width, int height){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    this.data = new int[width * height];
}

public BitMap(int[] data, int width, int height) {
    this.data = data;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

private int[] data;
private int width, height;

public int getWidth(){
    return width;
}

public int getHeight(){
    return height;
}

public int getValue(int x, int y){
    return data[x + y * width];
}

public BitMap fillWithValues(int value){
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        data[i] = value;
    }
    return this;
}

public void setValue(int xScr, int yScr, int value) {
    data[xScr + yScr * width] = value;
}

public int[] getValues() {
    return data;
}

public BitMap subData(int xPos, int yPos, int w, int h) {
    BitMap bitmap = new BitMap(w, h);
    for(int y = 0; y < h; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < w; x++){
            bitmap.setValue(x, y, this.getValue(x + xPos, y + yPos));
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem once by scaling the image up first 4X, rotating, than scaling back down.  It filled the holes quite nicely and wasn't to slow or difficult.  BitBank's answer is good also.  Working it backwards hadn't occurred to me.